# Can I use Ubuntu within Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, ubuntu-12.04

I want to use Ubuntu, but I already have Windows 8 on my laptop. How can I do this? Can I use Multiple Windows, Ubuntu and Windows8?

Comment: Is your laptop pre-installed with Windows 8 or you did an upgrade from a previous version of Windows - like Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and least-stressful way for you to do this is to install Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine and then just run the Virtual Machine.  Performance will depend a lot on how powerful your laptop is.  [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is popular for doing this.

If you want to do that as a dual boot and your laptop came with Windows 8, that's a fairly involved set of steps at the moment that I wouldn't recommend to a first-timer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Wubi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) to install Ubuntu side by side with Windows 8.

Comment: Unfortunately, wubi doesn't currently work with Windows 8 - [well, not on computers that come pre-installed with Windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system), at least.

Comment: @evilsoup have you tried the 12.04.2 ISO? Does it still cause issues? This version should support Secure Boot.